# Where should I put my enums and interfaces?

Tags: c#, architecture, asp.net-core

I have an asp core MVC project for a college and I would like to implement a timetabling feature.

To see if I could successfully even generate a dynamic HTML timetable, I started playing around in a separate console app. Naturally, the more I played, the more classes I ended up adding, and the more complex the HTML generating methods became, such that options could be passed to specify day and period lengths, render days at the top or side, add CSS classes etc.

So now, rather than just copy and paste all that code out of the one project and into the MVC layer of the other, I figured it would be pretty cool if I could just reference the timetable project and use the classes and methods in my asp views via that.  This would, in theory, also allow me to use the timetable in any other similar projects that might come along.

The main issue I'm pondering however is where should I put my enums and interfaces?

For example, to allow for alternative implementations of how to render a given timetable 'item' (e.g a class with its teacher and room) I thought I would use an interface. So the `Timetable` accepts a list of `ITimetableItem` which are responsible rendering a `<div>`, setting `colspan` and other relevant cells' `display` to `none`. I started defining interfaces in the domain level of my ASP app, but already I'm finding that I need an enum that is required for a `TimeTableItem` method that is called by the `Timetable` when generating the HTML.
Now, surely it wouldn't make sense to copy the enum into the Domain and have it exist in both? But also I don't want to reference the Timetable project from the Domain layer. This leads me to think that all interfaces and enums should live in the Timetable project, and my UI should reference the timetable project and implement it's interfaces? Is this a reasonable conclusion?

And finally (apologies for the huge post!) the `TimetableItem`s utilise classes such as `Teacher` and `Room`. Now in the console app I just built these up on the fly of course, but in the main project they exist and are much more complex than I necessarily need just to display a timetable. Would the solution also be interfaces? Is it normal to have interfaces for what seems like nearly all the classes I need in the Timetable? And then would I need special `TimeTableViewModel`classes for all said classes (`Teacher` etc.) that implement those interfaces, right?

Comment: As a general principle, if you want to share classes, enums, interfaces and other code artifacts (and avoid code duplication), you would put the shared/common code into its own module/assembly and reference that assembly from all places that use it.

Comment: `This would, in theory, also allow me to use the timetable in any other similar projects that might come along` - assuming by 'projects' you mean separate solutions (I may be wrong), it could be worth getting this into a NuGet package. The initial headache of configuring it will make distribution of these shared entities really easy.

Comment: Interesting, I was just thinking about asking, are there any significant differences, pros and cons between developing the 'timetable' in a solution all of it's own, or moving into a project within the main solution. Currently, while I work on both, it's a little annoyingly constantly building the one, then the other to test  and jumping between two instances of VS, but the clean separation is rather appealing.

Comment: If you are not planning to use that other library in other projects (right now) it's easier to just add it as an existing project to the main solution. You can switch to nugets anytime later when you start sharing it between other projects.